# Question in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f$ be a analytic in Domain $D$ which is an open disk of radius 1 centered at $z=0$ , it is given that in Domain $D$ , $|f(z)|\leq 1-|z|$ then prove that $f(z)=0$ in Domain $D$

It is asked that we have to prove $f(z) = 0$ using **Cauchy's Integral Formula**

I have attached my solution here [My solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eCxyo61IXAn2Pu3ARYMzJdZXMwzjMcD_) Please verify this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. A few notes: the second page could be substituted with a reductio ad absurdum: if $f(0)\neq 0$ and $f$ is constant, there is a $z:1-|z|<|f(0)|=|f(z)\le 1-|z|$.

In general, there's a faster approach to this kind of problems, by means of [the cauchy inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences) (which is an easy corollary of Cauchy integral formula) : given a function $f$ which is holomorphic in $B(z_0,R)$, we have that, $\forall r<R$:

$$|f^{(n)}(z_0)|\le n! r^{-n}\underset{|z-z_0|=r}{\sup}|f|$$

By Cauchy inequality and the hypotesis,

$|f^{(n)}(0)|\le n!r^{-n}\underset{|z|=r}{\sup}|f|\le n!r^{-n}(1-r)$

Letting $r\to 1^-$, we obtain

$$f(0)=0\\
\forall_{n>0}f^{(n)}(0)=0$$

Thus we have proved that $f$ is zero on the open unit disc

Comment: My Professor said that I can not write $|\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)(z)}|\leq \frac{1-R}{(r)(R)}$ , I am not satisfied with this argument , is it so?? He said that I can not separate numerator and denominator for finding Max Value ...

Comment: @xyz You can explain your inequality more by noting that for $a\ge 0, b>0$, $\max\frac{a}{b}\le \frac{\max(a)}{\min(b)}$